# want to use jsp:include.. but the jsp is returned through spring controller(view resolver)

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I revised my question.

(index.jsp, willwork.jsp ,WillWorkcontroller.java, another controller)

I have a Spring controller that returns a JSP through view resolver.
(I mean.. move from coltroller to jsp)
and I want to include willwork.jsp in main jsp

However, willwork.jsp has to be returned through controller!
so I don't know how to use  in index.jsp

here is my code

main jsp -> in contextPath

`<div class ="contents">
        <jsp:include page="${page}".jsp flush="false"></jsp:include> //it's wrong
</div>`

WillWork.java(contoller) -> package name : com.we2.willwork

```
@Controller
public class WillWorkController {

    private WillWorkDAO2 willWorkDAO;
    public void setWillWorkDAO(WillWorkDAO2 willWorkDAO) {
        this.willWorkDAO = willWorkDAO;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/willwork", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String initGet(Model model) throws ParseException{
    List<WillWorkVO> results = willWorkDAO.selectAll(); ...return "/WillWork/WillWork";
```

Willwork.jsp -> in WillWork folder

```
another controller! -> it returns main page and include page that will be included

@RequestMapping(value="/mailtest", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String pjt(Model model, String category) {
    model.addAttribute("page1","../WillWork/WillWork.jsp");
    return "myproject/myproject";
}
```

Comment: Park what do you mean with is not static JSP? that the "???" should change according to some parameter?

Comment: I just wanna use <jsp:include> to merge index.jsp with willwork.jsp   But willwork.jsp is returned through controller. So I dont know how to use jsp include....

Comment: If you see the jsp is returned by the controller, then just use Ajax to render the value of that JSP into the div with class="contents"

Comment: actually, I don't know using ajax exactly and I dont have time .. :( so I'm have to use this T.T

Comment: The page you want to render, have some logic to traduce? or is just plain html? if is just html, you could send a parameter to the index.jsp, compare it and use to render the proper page

Answer (score 0):

```
  <%@ include file="../CommonHeader/StudentHeader.jsp"%>
```

CommonHeader is folder present at web_inf/views/CommonHeader

and this included in web_inf/views/student/student.jsp this JSP file.

.. refers to the views folder in my case where my both jsp folder present